# Test if a polynomial is a square

Tags: polynomials, finite-fields

Let $F_q$ be a finite field. What is the best algorithm to test if a polynomial $f$ is a square? I am only interested in the regime q small respect to the degree of $f$.

Comment: This is far from my own field, but I would just calculate the gcd of $f$ and $f'$.

Answer (score 5):

Compute $g = f/\gcd(f, f')$, then (recursively) determine whether $h = f / g^2$ is a square.

If $f$ is a square, then all of its roots occur with even multiplicity, so it has a nontrivial $\gcd$ with its derivative.  Then $g$ has roots which are the repeated roots of $f$ with their multiplicities reduced to $1$.  Then $h$ is $f$ with all the multiplicities of its repeated roots reduced by $2$.  Iterating, we get a sequence of $h$s, $h_1, h_2, \dots h_k$, which terminates when $2k \geq \deg f$ (i.e., when $\gcd(f,f') = 1$) because the multiplicities of the roots of $f$ are finite.  If $h_k$ is a constant, then $h_{k-1}$ is a square, and so on, rolling back up to $f$ is a square.  If $h_k$ is not a constant, then $h_{k-1}$ is not a square, and so on, rolling back up to $f$ is not a square.

This is adapted from the usual first step of factoring polynomials, reduction to square-free form.  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials_over_finite_fields#Square-free_factorization) for more on this step.

---

Added in edit:

One way to detect that $h$ is not a square polynomial is that $h$ is not a polynomial.  That is $g^2 \nmid f$.  (Our way of constructing $g$ ensures this can't happen here, but it is a thing which can happen in more general settings.)

Note that this is "complicated" in characteristic $2$.  <del>I put that in quotes because every element is a square in characteristic $2$ (because the Frobenius map is surjective in finite fields), so a much easier algorithm in characteristic $2$ is `return True`.</del>(Not quite *that* easy, but still easy.)

---

Knuth (Art of Computer Programming, Vol. 2, p. 446) analyzes Berlekamp's algorithm modulo a prime $p$.  The first step of Berlekamp's algorithm, "step B1", computes $\gcd(f,f')$ in $O(n^2)$ time.  For large $q$, replace this with $O(n^2 (\log q)^2)$ to account for time computing inverses in $\mathbb{F}_q$ ([by any of several methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_field_arithmetic#Multiplicative_inverse)).  Here, $n = \deg f$.  The algorithm above has at most $\deg f/2$ $\gcd$s, so would seem to be $O(n^3)$ for your case of small $q$.

[Wikipedia suggests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorization_of_polynomials#Factoring_over_finite_fields) that [Berlekamp's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Berlekamp%27s_algorithm) and the [Cantor-Zassenhaus algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%E2%80%93Zassenhaus_algorithm) are the go-to algorithms for factoring over finite fields.  Both rely on $\gcd$s, so I don't see that there are evident alternatives to the algorithm above.

There *are* some sneaky algorithms for factoring modulo primes, $p$, having $p-1$ smooth (i.e., factoring into small numbers).  See [Factoring polynomials modulo special primes](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiN1tuF2ZnYAhVk9YMKHSKwDkUQFggvMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Flink.springer.com%2Fcontent%2Fpdf%2F10.1007%2FBF02124680.pdf&usg=AOvVaw0APfapFPFmGgE7ddEh2ou9).  I'm not familiar with these methods.

Comment: Thanks this is indeed the only kind of algorithm I could think of, so your guess is that there is no better algorithm to do so?

Comment: @Reyx_0 : Better in what way?  You haven't given a criterion or criteria for evaluating the "goodness" of such algorithms in your question or in your comment.

Comment: Just in terms of running time

Comment: In characteristic $2$, polynomials containing solely even-degree terms are squares.  So the algorithm isn’t quite “return True” but it still is very straightforward.  Maybe you are referring to the base case of constant polynomial, but I didn’t see any discussion of computing Legendre symbols etc.

Comment: @Reyx_0 There is another obvious algorithm besides this one: just extract the square root term-by-term similar to grade-school long division.  It might even be that Newton's method combined with fast polynomial division algorithms could beat out this algorithm in the extreme case of a square or almost-square where we'd have to descend pretty far.

Comment: @Reyx_0 Likewise, there is probably a Newton's method variant that works from the lowest-degree end, using inversion modulo $x^n$ (over $\mathbb F_q$ instead of polynomial division.

Comment: @ErickWong : If you want to write an Answer, then write one.  Scattering your thoughts across multiple comments is of very little use.

Comment: @ErickWong : Re: $\mathrm{char}\  2$: Yeah...  Didn't describe the $\mathrm{char} \ 2$ case correctly.  (I've most recently been working in a setting where the evaluation homomorphism is always implicitly applied, so Fermat's little theorem also applies to indeterminates.  In any event, edited out.)